# Android : Connect to a real server but not on a localhost

Tags: android, post

I have am trying to connect to a server via a AVD. When I connect to a real serveur it works just fine but when I'm trying to connect on the same server but on localhost, I have a response **code 400** (*definition* :The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.) **BTW**, I changed localhost by 10.0.2.2 as I saw on other topics.
Here's my code :

```
private final String SERVER = "http://10.0.2.2:51502/example/example";

protected String doInBackground(String... strJson ) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(SERVER);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(strJson[0]);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }

        }
        else {
            response="PAS DE HTTP_OK : " + responseCode;

        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        response = "malformedURL" + e.toString();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        response = "Protocol" + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = "IOException" + e.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "Exception" + e.toString();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Ask whoever created your server why it is returning a 400 response. If you created the server, check the logs, look for error messages, etc.

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again? Within two hours! You should have answered the comments on your other post. And you have the same errors in your code as before. What does it help if people try to help you and you throw it all away?

Comment: @greenappsMy previous question was "is it posible to see the URL of a POST request ?" You answered me that what I was trying to do is impossible. Now I switched my question to "Why have I an error 400". Didn't want to have multipl question on a same topic. And sorry I didn't see that you answered me on the previous topic